# How to use a (indirect) reference in the array input for SUMPRODUCT in excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I have two tables in excel of which I would like to take the sumproduct.

Table 1:

```
  |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |  G   |  H   |  I   |  J   |  
=========================================================================
1 | 1    |      |      |      |      | 2    |      |      |      |      |       
2 | ABC  | BAC  | CDE  | DSW  | FSA  | ABC  | BAC  | CDE  | DSW  | FSA  |
3 | 3    | 2    | 4    | 1    | 3    | 2    | 5    | 2    | 4    | 3    |
...
n | f(1) |      |      |      |      | f(2) |      |      |      |      |
```

Table 2:

```
   |  X  |  Y  |
================
10 | ABC | 10  |
11 | BAC | 15  |
12 | CDE | 12  |
13 | DSW | 8   |
14 | FSA | 17  |
```

Table 1 is the input table with repeating columns of ABC, etc. indexed with the number for the current section in row 1. Table 2 is a reference with 'rates' that apply to the values below ABC, etc.

In row n I want to apply a universal formula that only takes the sumproduct of the current section i.e. columns A-E or F-J. I have an if statement that ensures that only in columns A and F the below formula will apply:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:ADDRESS(ROW(A3);MATCH(A$1+1;$1:$1;0)-1);Y10:Y14)
```

SUMPRODUCT receives two arrays for the product. The first one is composed from the known reference A3 and should extend to the last field in the same section and row (E3). This is the part I cannot get to work.

The trick is that some columns at the end may be left out. Hence the exact same formula should work also for the below (alternate) case for Table 1.

```
  |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |  G   |  H   | 
===========================================================
1 | 1    |      |      | 2    |      |      |      |      |     
2 | ABC  | BAC  | CDE  | ABC  | BAC  | CDE  | DSW  | FSA  |
3 | 3    | 2    | 4    | 2    | 5    | 2    | 4    | 3    |
...
n | f(1) |      |      | f(2) |      |      |      |      |
```

The result so far is that I receive an error using ADDRESS as input for the array.

I did try INDIRECT, but without success so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INDEX/MATCH` to get the correct range.....but if it might not be 5 cells you won't be able to multiply it by `Y10:Y14` so perhaps try this version:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(X10:X14;A2:INDEX(2:2;MATCH(A$1+1;$1:$1;0)-1);Y10:Y14);A3:INDEX(3:3;MATCH(A$1+1;$1:$1;0)-1))`